# Folder URL from .onDrop() modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to read the contents of a folder by getting its URL from an .onDrop() modifier.

The starting point is [SwiftOnTap's example on how to process an NSItemProvider](https://swiftontap.com/view/ondrop(of:istargeted:perform:)-b7eed), but it's not resulting in anything.

How do I extract the URL from an NSItemProvider of UTType "public.url"?

```
.onDrop(of: ["public.url"], isTargeted: $dropping, perform: { itemProvider in
    if let item = itemProvider.first {
        item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (folder, err) in
            if let data = folder as? Data {
                let droppedString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                print(droppedString)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public.url` alone doesn't appear to work for folders, but if your constrain it further to `public.file-url`, it does work. (Tested on macOS 11.2.3):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dropping = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], isTargeted: $dropping, perform: { itemProvider in
            if let item = itemProvider.first {
                _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { (url, error) in
                    if let url = url {
                        print("URL:", url)
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!